# Llamar a un formulario wpf contenido en una dll

Tags: c#, wpf

Mi pregunta es muy concreta. Digamos que tengo un ensamblado c# y que quiero que mis interfaces del ensamblado sean xaml. Como puedo crearme formularios wpf y llamarlos dentro del ensamblado sin estar dentro del ensamblado ejecutable que monta un proyecto wpf y que ya viene predefinido el inicio por app.xaml.
Hablando de Form simplemente nos creamos un formulario, instanciamos y lo llamamos con show. ¿Como puedo hacer lo mismo con WPF?

Comment: Tu dices cargar los XAML desde una Biblioteca de Clases?
Si es eso solo debes crear las interfaces como UserControl en la biblioteca de clases, luego esa biblioteca la importas en tu proyecto como una 'referencia'. 
Para usarla solo agregas una nueva ventana vacía, creas un 'xmlns' (xmlns:z=".....") en esa ventana que haga referencia a la DLL que importaste y listo, dentro de la ventana en vez del grid pones la referencia y el nombre del formulario respetando los namespaces internos claro está (<z:MiFormulario/>).

Luego le pones un nombre (x:Name) y ya puedes acceder al formulario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si te refieres a mostar una ventana de tipo `System.Windows.Window` que esta contenida en una dll, puedes lograrlo con reflection.

Primero tienes que cargar la dll que tu formulario utilizando [`Assembly.LoadFrom()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.loadfrom(v=vs.110).aspx). Este metodo recibe la ruta de la dll y retorna un objeto de tipo [`Assembly`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
System.Reflection.Assembly assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom("ruta_dll.dll");
```

Luego buscas la clase que sea de tipo `Window` utilizando el metodo `Assembly#GetTypes()`:

```
var windowsType = typeof(System.Windows.Window);
assembly.GetTypes().Where(type=> type == windowType);
```

Como ya tienes todas la clase que son de tipo `Window` que representa los formulario, solo te quedaria inicializar las instanicas de lo mismos utilizando el metodo `Activator.CreateInstance()`:

```
var windowInstances = windowsType.Select(x=> Activator.CreateInstance(x) as System.Windows.Window);
```

Entonces para mostralo solo tendrias que ejecutar el metodo `Window#Show()`:

```
windowInstances.FirstOrDefault()?.Show();
```

Nota que utilizo `FirstOrDefault()` ya que se entiende que en la libreria solo tendrias una clase que hereda de `System.Windows.Window`. Si tienes varias, tendras que inventar un mecanismo para mostrar solo el formulario que deseas.

Aqui el codigo completo:

```
var windowsType = typeof(System.Windows.Window);

var windowInstances = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom("ruta_dll.dll")
                .GetTypes()
                .Where(type=> type == windowType)
                .Select(Activator.CreateInstance);

windowInstances.FirstOrDefault()?.Show();
```